# How to set up groups in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, count

Suppose I have the following table of users. How can I set groups of 5 as it appears in the group column? The idea is that each group contains 5 users.

```
user    group
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   2
7   2
8   2
9   2
10  2
11  3
12  3
13  3
14  3
15  3
16  4
17  4
18  4
19  4
20  4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:A), 1, 0)/5)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: As a way to complete this answer by providing further explanation I can add that [COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en) will get the total number of values in your column A first. Then [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en) will create an array with the number of rows of the value provided by ```COUNTA```, 1 column and starting at  0. Then this array gets divided by 5 ```(20/5 = 4)``` and in case we have 21 values [ROUNDDOWN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093442?hl=en) is used to round the total number.

Comment: Finally, with [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) we return the content of our array.

Answer (score 2):

One more option:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),ROUNDUP((ROW(A2:A)-1)/5),""))
```

[image]